# Problems with IPC SendMessage

Tags: delphi, dll, ipc, windows-messages

Hi I'm having problems with my `SendMessage`.

It seams like the message never reaches my form (I'm using Winspector Spy to see which messages that are registered in my form), which is strange because I'm shure I'm sending to  the correct Handle for the current form.

The SendMessage is within a dll but that should not have any thing to do with it.

```
//sStr is just an input where i type in the Handler address;  
SendMessage(Integer(sStr),WM_COPYDATA, Integer(Handle),Integer(@copyDataStruct));
```

SendMessage returns 0 every time.

On the receiving end:

```
procedure WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData); message WM_CopyData;

procedure TMainForm.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
 s : string;
begin
    s := PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
    showmessage(s);
 //Send something back
    msg.Result := 2006;
end;
```

I have also tried other messages like WM_CLOSE. Do any one know why this fails? 
I'm using Delphi 5.

Comment: Are you sure that you pass the right window handle to SendMessage? Please check that first. And I assume that this is a normal forms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you *cannot* write

```
Integer(sStr)
```

to convert a string representing an integer (e.g. '12345') to an integer (12345).

Use

```
StrToInt(sStr)
```

instead.

Indeed, technically, a string is only a pointer to the string header + data. I guess that `Integer(sStr)` simply returns that pointer. (Or, actually, simply treats the sStr like an integer).

That is, you should do

```
SendMessage(StrToInt(sStr), WM_COPYDATA, Handle, cardinal(@copyDataStruct));
```

Comment: Well, it is more than a suggestion. It will *definitely* not work if you write `Integer(sStr)`. When I did a test, `Integer('12345') = 4605000`.

Comment: Yes well im using it, sorry if i sounded sharp or did not take in what you said, im just saying that it did not solve my problem, its been a long day of programming :)

Comment: This morning it suddenly worked out of the blue, dont what was wrong but im shure this helped some, did not to any changes. So ill set this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The SendMessage definition is

```
function SendMessage(hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM):LRESULT; stdcall;
```

**Updated**

For Msg = wm_copydata:

- The first argument is a handle to the
  window receiving the data
- The third argument is a handle to the window
  passing the data

If you name the first argument sStr I assume it is not a handle but a string.

Comment: Wrong how ? my fist parm  sStr is the handle to the receiving window, WM_CopyData is the message, Handle is the handle to the dll and @copyDataStruct is the data thats to be sent. I dont se the fault here.

Comment: @Rosie: What data type is `sStr`?

Comment: sStr is a string. Which i manually type in the Handel for the targeting form.

Comment: @Roise: If sStr is a string, it isn't a Window handle (HWND). HWND's are numeric (LONGWORD). String <> LONGWORD in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use the name or something for your window, and that won't work.

Try this instead:

```
var
  Wnd: HWnd;
begin
  Wnd := GetForegroundWindow(); // Assumes your target window is up front
  // Fill in CopyData structure here.
  SendMessage(Wnd, WM_COPYDATA, SomeWParamValue, Cardinal(@CopyDataStruct));
end;
```